# re-arrange date from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this string here:

```
value.dateCompleted.split(" ")[0];
```

and this returns: `30/11/2015`

I need rearrange this date so its `2015/11/30`

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just split it, reverse it and glue it back again...

```
value.dateCompleted.split(" ")[0].split('/').reverse().join('/');
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/jxw0oqn2/